# Cross dataframe columns "contains List" with dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pivot-table

I am trying to create dataframe . from a combination of dataframe with a cross dictionary  as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY1Ns.jpg)

dataframe contains multiple columns "N numbers of columns x,y,z,a,b,c ......etc more than 100 columns "

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['EF407412','KM043272']
               , 'x': ['[2788, 3140, 4836]','[539, 906, 1494, 1932, 2029,7001]']
               , 'y': ['[1408, 1572, 2277]','[]']
               # dataframe contains multiple columns "N numbers of columns x,y,z,a,b,c ......etc more than 100 columns " 
               })
```

dictionary name is scale, and its items (keys to values) are Customizable and transformation rules from input dataframe to output dataframe were mentioned in the below comments

```
scale = ("500-10000", {

# Key= Scales and value = Weights, both Customizable

    500: 7000,   #  key is 500 and value is compared with List as  List items >= 7000
2500: 3000,  #  key is 2500 and value is compared with List as  List 7000 > items >= 3000
5000: 1000,  #  key is 5000 and value is compared with List as  List 3000 > items >= 1000
7500: 400,   #  key is 7500 and value is compared with List as  List 1000 > items >= 400
10000:250    #  key is 10000 and value is compared with List as  List 400 > items >= 250
             #  any others List items < 250 will be neglected 
             #  any others List items < 250 will be neglected })
```

important p.s >>> If the input list items contain redundant data, it will be treated in the output as separate values. for example x column contain List [4836, 4836, 4836] output inside column of x_2500 will be [4836, 4836, 4836]

Comment: @Abhishek hello friend Abhishek, Can I have your kind support as usual?

Comment: Is there a value missing in column `x_7500` row `1`? Isn't 906 > 400 less than 1000?

Comment: @IanThompson 
ooh, yes its a typo, post is updated thanks for your kind support and feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your `df` and `scale` objects...

```
def make_new_columns(series: pd.Series) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Given column, make new columns using `scale`."""
    # convert str representation of list to literal list
    series = series.apply(ast.literal_eval)
    
    scale_dict = scale[1]
    
    frames = []
    for k, v in scale_dict.items():
        k_frame = pd.DataFrame({f"{series.name}_{k}": series.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i >= v])})
        frames.append(k_frame)
        
    frame = pd.concat(frames, axis="columns")
    
    cols = frame.columns[frame.columns.str.startswith(f"{series.name}_")]
    
    for col0, col1 in zip(cols, cols[1:]):
        frame[f"{col1}_"] = frame[[col0, col1]].applymap(set).apply(lambda x: x[col1].difference(x[col0]), axis=1)
    
    # the first `x_...` col is `x_500` and will not change -- remove others
    frame = frame.drop(columns=cols[1:])
    
    frame.columns = frame.columns.str.strip("_")
    
    frame[cols] = frame[cols].applymap(lambda x: [0] if not len(x) else list(x))
    
    return frame

# apply `make_new_columns` to x, y, z, a, b, c, ...
cols_to_apply = df.loc[:, "x":].columns

to_join = []
for col in cols_to_apply:
    new = make_new_columns(df[col])
    to_join.append(new)

df = df[["ID"]].join(to_join)

df
```

[image: output]

Comment: thanks, @IanThompson but I have the below error 
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I believe that is from your "lists" being string representations of lists. I made them actual lists instead of strings. I'll add that to the code.

Comment: Thanks Ian, Can you please consider in your solution that I am looking to apply the same in all input dataframe columns once,  input dataframe contains multiple columns "N numbers of columns x,y,z,a,b,c ......etc around 900 columns

Comment: converted the code to a function that can be applied to whatever columns you need

Comment: Super Thanks @IanThompson more than perfect

Comment: Dear @IanThompson, your solution missed an important point " If the input list items contain redundant data, it will be treated in the output as separate values. for example, x column containing List [4836, 4836, 4836] output inside column of x_2500 will be [4836, 4836, 4836]" Can you please review it ?? waiting for your feedback ASAP, and thanks for your kind support

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df["x"] = df["x"].apply(literal_eval)
df["y"] = df["y"].apply(literal_eval)

x = df.set_index("ID").stack().to_frame().explode(0).dropna()

x["name"] = pd.cut(
    x[0],
    list(scale[1].values())[::-1] + [float("inf")],
    right=False,
    labels=list(scale[1])[::-1],
)
x["tmp"] = x.index.get_level_values(1)

x = x.pivot_table(
    index=pd.Grouper(level=0),
    columns=["tmp", "name"],
    values=0,
    aggfunc=list,
)

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [set(x.columns.get_level_values(0)), scale[1].keys()]
)

x = x.reindex(idx, axis=1)
x.columns = [f"{a}_{b}" for a, b in x.columns]
x = x.apply(lambda s: s.fillna({i: [0] for i in x.index}))

print(
    x[
        sorted(x.columns, key=lambda x: (x.split("_")[0], int(x.split("_")[1])))
    ].reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
         ID   x_500        x_2500              x_5000      x_7500 x_10000 y_500 y_2500              y_5000 y_7500 y_10000
0  EF407412     [0]  [3140, 4836]              [2788]         [0]     [0]   [0]    [0]  [1408, 1572, 2277]    [0]     [0]
1  KM043272  [7001]           [0]  [1494, 1932, 2029]  [539, 906]     [0]   [0]    [0]                 [0]    [0]     [0]
```

Comment: Thanks, @AndrejKesely your code is also perfect, your effort is much appreciated 

Comment: Dear @AndrejKesely, can you please enhance your code to support Multiple columns instead of the proposed one for x,y columns only ?? df dataframe contains multiple columns "N numbers of columns x,y,z,a,b,c ......etc more than 100 columns "